# r.write('\n') cuts off needed data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#get website, trick website into thinking you're using chrome.
url = 'http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/sort/wins/league/al/year/2019/seasontype/2'
headers ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
res = requests.get(url, headers)

#sets soup to res and spits it out in html parsing format
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

#finds table from website
stats = soup.find_all('table', class_='tablehead')
stats = stats[0]

#saves the table into a text file.
with open('pitchers_stats.txt', 'w') as r:

 for row in stats.find_all('tr'):
    r.write(row.text.ljust(5))
    #delete next two lines. the program sort of works, for those trying to help me on stackOverflow.
    for cell in stats.find_all('td'):
        r.write('\n')
    # divide each row by a new line
    r.write('\n')
```

simply prints out "Sortable pitching"
and i'm not sure why.

the program sort of works as expected by deleting the lines:

```
for cell in stats.find_all('td'):
  r.write('\n')
```

^doing this shows the following:
.

[image]

Comment: What's your question exactly? You said the program works when removing the lines you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to parse the table and post each column on a new line.

The issue is that you're trying to parse the content of the `<tr>` tag. What you should do instead is iterating the `<td>` elements inside it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#get website, trick website into thinking you're using chrome.
url = 'http://www.espn.com/mlb/stats/pitching/_/sort/wins/league/al/year/2019/seasontype/2'
headers ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
res = requests.get(url, headers)

#sets soup to res and spits it out in html parsing format
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

#finds table from website
stats = soup.find_all('table', class_='tablehead')
stats = stats[0]

#saves the table into a text file.
with open('pitchers_stats.txt', 'w') as r:
 for row in stats.find_all('tr'):
    for data in row.find_all('td'):
        r.write(data.text.ljust(5))
        r.write('\n')
    r.write('\n')
```

Comment: that returns this
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/526891145733603339/675444984991973465/unknown.png

Comment: Can't seem to recreate that one. https://i.imgur.com/riBwoGX.png

Comment: oops, i see what I did wrong. but now there is something odd happening.
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/526891145733603339/675448804920786956/unknown.png

Comment: Please make sure you're using the exact same code in the answer. I updated it to the full code

Comment: I made yet another mistake and fixed it. thanks for your help @Kasem